# How to use the same function like Oracle Rownum in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, rownum

I am encountering a problem, I had done a function that the data can be loaded by detecting scrolling position, the function was made with a SQL statement "Rownum", it only works in Oracle, but not in ACCESS.

I would like to query the data and resort it

```
ID  value
1   aa
3   bb
```

with Rownum we can do like this

```
NID ID value
1   1  aa
2   3  bb
```

how can I write a SQL statement with Microsoft ACCESS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access does not support that function.  If your `ID` field is a numeric primary key, you can include a field expression which is the count of the number of rows with `ID` <= to the current `ID` value.

```
SELECT
    DCount('*', 'YourTable', 'ID <= ' & y.ID) AS NID,
    y.ID,
    y.value
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

You could use a correlated subquery instead of `DCount` if you prefer.

And `ID` does not actually have to be a primary key.  If it has a unique constraint it is still suitable for this purpose.

And the targeted field does not absolutely have to be a number, but text data type can be more challenging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!It looks almost done, but I would like to plus "where" like this"SELECT  DCount('*', 'Article', 'ID <= ' & y.ID) AS NID,  y.ID,  y.Topic FROM Article AS y where NID between 1 and 2"

because I would like to specify load range of items~~ I add like that but it does not work..

Comment: Consider `TOP 2` ... `SELECT TOP 2 DCount('*', 'Article', 'ID <= ' & y.ID) AS NID, y.ID, y.Topic FROM Article AS y ORDER BY y.ID;`

Comment: And also thanks for revising my format, it looks better indeed!

Comment: is it possible being a range? between 1 and 2 is just a example~~ once if I want to select between 15 and 30, how can I make it? Thanks!

Comment: Save the first query (the one without `TOP`) as *qryStep1*.  Then create a second query which uses the first as its data source: `SELECT * FROM qryStep1 WHERE NID BETWEEN 15 AND 30;`